# calling two classes functions to one sorted output

Tags: php, web

im surfing in index.php file and My code is this:

index.php =

```
require("template.php"); // the file with the template of the site

$title="Home";
$phead='';
$html->htmlhead();

$htmlside="";
$html->htmlside();

require("file2.php"); // a file with class $queans and function question()
$htmlbody = $queans->questions();
$html->htmlbody($htmlbody);

$htmlfoot="";
$html->htmlfoot();
```

template.php = contain class $html and all it functions that i wrote at the previous file. and the spific proflem with the htmlbody function:

```
//all the class plugin
//in this specific function i wrote
$html->htmlbody($htmlbody){
   echo '<div id="s">'.$htmlbody.'</div>';
}
```

file2.php =

```
$queans = new ques;
class ques{
    public function questions(){
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

at the end it shows me the output of `$queans->questions()` before the output of `function questions()` and the output is like:

```
test
<div id="s">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your file2.php you have to return 'test' instead of echoing it.

Comment: i tried it. its dont work when i have a regular html to output and a while with few results  also to return. 2 returns needed and i cant use 2, am i wrong?

Comment: Two returns where? In the questions() function? You can have a variable that in the loop is concatenated ($var .= $more_text)